# Finding a minimum of a row in a matrix

Tags: r, statistics, minimum, uniform

I've been asked for an assignment to generate 1000 random samples of size 100 from a Uniform[0,1] distribution. For each sample, record the minimum. Then find the mean and variance of these minima.

I used this code so far so that I can have all my samples in a matrix with 1000 rows and 100 columns. (I think that's what it is doing).

```
x <- matrix(runif(100000,0,1),1000,100)
```

So now I need to find the minimum of each row, then from there I need the expected and variance and I really don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe read up documentation in `?apply`

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
apply(x,2,min)
```

You will get min values for each column